# Robotframework Return SQL Query as CSV (not dict)

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, robotframework

Version: Robot Framework 3.2.2 (Python 3.11.4 on darwin)

I'm using the DatabaseLibrary with psycopg2 to query a simple table in PostgreSQL:

`${psql_results}=    Query    SELECT * FROM myTable`

The problem is that this library returns the SQL results as dict, not simple comma-separated values. In most cases that is fine; although cumbersome requiring additional code, I can use different things like json.dumps() or DataFrame.from_Dict() type conversions etc to get the CSV format, which is what I need.

Depending on the complexity of the data (eg:- Decimal, etc), the above methods hit a brick wall.

There are probably some ways to circumvent those blocks and use the above methods, but I was just wondering, is there any way to execute an SQL Query from RobotFramework for PostgreSQL and just simply get comma separated column values?

I'm getting this:

```
[
    {first:"sponge", last:"bob", skill:"line cook"}
    {first:"Squid", last:"Ward", skill:"Clarinet"
]
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
first,last,skill
sponge,bob,"line cook"
squid,ward,clarinet
```

Maybe there's a different library or something I can use that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: `In most cases that is fine; although cumbersome requiring additional code` actually, it's always fine. People never want to retrieve query results as a string that requires splitting. You're asking for a very specific functionality, which a) is actually already available and b) has nothing do do with test automation or "robots". First of all, PostgreSQL itself can export query results as CSV. In Python, if you use Pandas, `DataFrame.to_csv` will save loaded data as CSV. Python's own `csv` module can write tuples to a CSV file with `writer.writerow(row)`.

Comment: If you search StackOverflow for `psycopg2 csv` you'll find a lot of answers that either use PostgreSQL's `COPY` to generate the output text or use the `csv` module, iterate over the results and write each row to the CSV file. Libraries like Pandas or Polars go further, taking care of date and number format issues.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried variants of the methods you've suggested above, but none of them have worked for me for reason or another. COPY or \copy both throw: "UndefinedFile: could not open file "file.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy."
pd.read_json() or from_dict() both throw errors of different kind, so I can't use .to_csv. CSV.writer has been throwing something else. I don't understand why none of them work!

Comment: Do you have an example of the COPY or \copy from Robot Framework? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Adding:

Something like `${results}=    Execute SQL String    \copy (SELECT * FROM myTable) to 'try.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV` or variants of it all just throw errors. This statement works perfectly fine in postgresql console, but not in robot.